# Why gwibber-service keeps poping up even if I deleted Gwibber?

Tags: 12.04, performance, gwibber

**My Ubuntu 12.04 had been getting annoyingly slow during the day..**

So I decided to have a terminal running [top](http://www.unixtop.org/) in one of my monitors at all times. I noticed that gwibber-service - gwibber is a ubuntu default application - was poping up in the top of cpu usage plenty of times.

I deleted it.

Now days after its deletion I keep seeing the process gwibber-service popping up! I kill it by its PID , but what I really want to know is **why** that process is running there after the application was deleted. Of course how to completely remove it won't hurt

**[Update]** Reverse dependancy on gwibber-service check shows these packages:
gwibber-service

gwibber:i386

ubuntu-sugar-remix

desktopcouch

ubuntu-desktop

I think [desktopcouch](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/desktopcouch) is responsible for this as it is what ubuntu uses to synchronize (thunderbird, ubuntu one, social media..).  I really want to know why this part of gwibber is not deleted with standard uninstall. Should I report somewhere?

Comment: Looks like you've not deleted it after all. Running something like `sudo apt-get purge gwibber*` should do the job.

Comment: @mikewhatever he may have just removed the gwibber package. For some reason, removing that does not remove the gwibber-service package, at least in 12.10.

Comment: It should, if you don't forget the star sign at the end.

Comment: @mikewhatever I know your command will work, I was just saying he might have just uninstalled only the `gwibber` package and didn't use the star or explicitly uninstall the the others.

Comment: @mikewhatever do you mind that I added the `purge` command to my answer after seeing your comment and remembering that it should be used to remove configuration files also?

Comment: @mspencer Not at all. If you find it useful, please do so.

Answer (score 1):

Running `whereis gwibber-service` shows

```
gwibber-service: /usr/bin/gwibber-service /usr/bin/X11/gwibber-service
```

`gwibber-service` isn't in the `gwibber` package. Instead, it is in the `gwibber-service` package.

For some reason, uninstalling the `gwibber` package doesn't uninstall the `gwibber-service` package also. You'll have to uninstall that separately, which you can do using this command:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove gwibber-service
```

If you want to also remove configuration files, run

```
sudo apt-get purge gwibber-service
```

Comment: +1 for uninstall tips. Thanks guys but what I really want to know is why that thing is there. This is not windows, right :)?